# Remix simple storage invalid argument error

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    
    uint256 favoriteNumber;


    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    People[] public people;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    } 

    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
       return favoriteNumber;
        
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public{
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am assuming the error is not in the .sol file but somewhere else.
I am following an online guide. Repo: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py#inheritance-factory-pattern-and-interacting-with-external-contracts

Comment: What function are you calling that gives you the invalid argument error? Please include steps to reproduce

Comment: What arguments are you sending to which function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JulissaDC apologies, i've made a mistake. I didn't index the storage which the function should retrieve. There is no mistake in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter  the name like  "Patrick" , 2